# Crashing with custom navigation controller

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I ran into an issue when testing my application in iOS7. The application currently runs just fine in iOS5 and iOS6. Based on the stack trace, it would appear that a private method is causing the issue.

```
2013-11-21 17:00:56.565 MyApp[706:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'An override of -[UINavigationController navigationBar] is returning an object that is not a kind of UINavigationBar'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0244d5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01eee8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0244d3bb +[NSException raise:format:] + 139
    3   UIKit                               0x00af796c -[UINavigationController _confirmBarAccessMethods] + 277
    4   UIKit                               0x00af7b19 -[UINavigationController initWithNibName:bundle:] + 271
    5   MyApp                               0x000b8bd8 -[CustomUINavigationController initWithNibName:bundle:] + 152
    6   UIKit                               0x00af77b3 -[UINavigationController initWithRootViewController:] + 86
    7   MyApp                               0x000b8ea1 -[CustomUINavigationController initWithRootViewController:] + 113
    8   MyApp                               0x0000260a -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 666
    9   UIKit                               0x009c7355 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 309
    10  UIKit                               0x009c7b95 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1536
    11  UIKit                               0x009cc3a8 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 824
    12  UIKit                               0x009e087c -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3447
    13  UIKit                               0x009e0de9 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
    14  UIKit                               0x009ce025 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 736
    15  GraphicsServices                    0x0478b2f6 _PurpleEventCallback + 776
    16  GraphicsServices                    0x0478ae01 PurpleEventCallback + 46
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x023c8d65 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x023c8a9b __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x023f377c __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x023f2ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x023f28db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    22  UIKit                               0x009cbadd -[UIApplication _run] + 840
    23  UIKit                               0x009cdd3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    24  MyApp                               0x00002337 main + 295
    25  MyApp                               0x00002205 start + 53
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

This crash happens only when testing in iOS7. It happens as soon as `[super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]` is called. I cannot find any information about `_confirmBarAccessMethods`. I assume it is a private `UINavigationController` method.

Here is the header file for the `CustomUINavigationController` class:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CustomUINavigationBar.h"

@interface CustomUINavigationController : UINavigationController
{
    CustomUINavigationBar *customNavigationBar;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIColor *titleColor;

@end
```

This is the init method in which the application crashes:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];   // This line causes the application to crash
    if (self) {
        customNavigationBar = [[CustomUINavigationBar alloc] init];
        [customNavigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:1.0]];
        [customNavigationBar setItems:[NSArray array] animated:NO];
        [customNavigationBar setDelegate:self];

        self.titleColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:1.0];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Here is the header file for `CustomNavigationBar`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomUINavigationBar : UINavigationBar
{
UIImage *background;
}

@end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I can provide more information if necessary.

EDIT: Added trace from suggested solution of using custom navigation bar initializer

```
2013-11-22 13:04:49.756 MyApp[390:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'An override of -[UINavigationController navigationBar] is returning an object that is not a kind of UINavigationBar'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0244d5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01eee8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0244d3bb +[NSException raise:format:] + 139
    3   UIKit                               0x00af796c -[UINavigationController _confirmBarAccessMethods] + 277
    4   UIKit                               0x00af7b19 -[UINavigationController initWithNibName:bundle:] + 271
    5   MyApp                               0x000b8e38 -[CustomUINavigationController initWithNibName:bundle:] + 152
    6   UIKit                               0x00af7815 -[UINavigationController initWithNavigationBarClass:toolbarClass:] + 52
    7   MyApp                               0x00002868 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 712
    8   UIKit                               0x009c7355 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 309
    9   UIKit                               0x009c7b95 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1536
    10  UIKit                               0x009cc3a8 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 824
    11  UIKit                               0x009e087c -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3447
    12  UIKit                               0x009e0de9 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
    13  UIKit                               0x009ce025 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 736
    14  GraphicsServices                    0x0478b2f6 _PurpleEventCallback + 776
    15  GraphicsServices                    0x0478ae01 PurpleEventCallback + 46
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x023c8d65 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x023c8a9b __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x023f377c __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x023f2ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x023f28db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    21  UIKit                               0x009cbadd -[UIApplication _run] + 840
    22  UIKit                               0x009cdd3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    23  MyApp                               0x00002567 main + 295
    24  MyApp                               0x00002435 start + 53
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Is CustomUIBavigationBar a subclass of UINavigationBar?

Comment: Yes, I will add the class definition in the question for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved the issue. `CustomerUINavigationController` had an override method for the `navigationBar` accessor. It was attempting to return a nil value. I removed this and the application compiled and ran with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

Create the navigation controller with `initWithNavigationBarClass:toolbarClass:` and supply your custom navigation bar class. Then perform any configuration you require on the instance created for you by the nav controller superclass.

Comment: I changed `myNavController = [[CustomUINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myViewController];` to `myNavController = [[CustomUINavigationController alloc] initWithNavigationBarClass:[CustomUINavigationBar class] toolbarClass:nil];` and it resulted in the same error.

Comment: Exactly the same exception?

Comment: Yes, exact same stack trace as well.

Comment: There should be no `UINavigationController initWithRootViewController:` in the trace.

Comment: I will run it again and give the full stack trace.